# How to remove lines from a data frame using another dataframe

Tags: r, dataset, filter, subset

although there are many results out there none seems to answer my question below:
I have two data frames

```
df1 = data.frame(x= c("a1","b1","c1","d1","e1","f1"),y =  c("a2","b2","c2","d2","e2","f2"), z = 1:6)

df2 = data.frame(x = c("a1", "b1"), y = c("a2", "b2"))
```

they return:

```
> df1
   x  y z
1 a1 a2 1
2 b1 b2 2
3 c1 c2 3
4 d1 d2 4
5 e1 e2 5
6 f1 f2 6


> df2
   x  y
1 a1 a2
2 b1 b2
```

How can I get the remaining of their inner join, I mean I want to get:

```
   x  y z

1 c1 c2 3
2 d1 d2 4
3 e1 e2 5
4 f1 f2 6
```

I tried

`subset(df1, (df1$x %in% df2$x) & (df1$y %in% df2$y)` )

but it doesn' t work also tried left join, but I keep getting the original data frame df1

Comment: You need `dplyr::anti_join(df1, df2)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a key made up by combining the first and second columns together and then using the `%in%` function.

```
df1 = data.frame(x= c("a1","b1","c1","d1","e1","f1"),y =  c("a2","b2","c2","d2","e2","f2"), z = 1:6)

df2 = data.frame(x = c("a1", "b1"), y = c("a2", "b2"))

#create a unique key for each dataframe
df1key<-paste(df1$x, df1$y)
df2key<-paste(df2$x, df2$y)

#return rows not matching rows in df2
answer<-df1[!(df1key  %in%  df2key),]
```